# Firefox properties

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to access firefox properties, more specifically the launcher options I'm given following instructions:

Ubuntu (and other GNOME-based distributions):

1. Click on the Preferences menu and select Main menu. The Main Menu window appears.
2. Click on the program group called Internet.
3. Select Firefox Web Browser and click on the Properties button. The Launcher properties window appears.
4. Insert the string `env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` before the text specified in the Command field:

However when I click on Firefox Web Browser under the program group called internet it simply opens another window, if I right click on it it also opens another window, where may I find the "properties button"?

Comment: Can you please include the link to the instructions you are trying to follow.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/flash-video-wont-play-full-screen I would like to open firefox launch properties, but I'm unable to, I'm using firefox 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions look like they are for a really old version of Ubuntu using gnome and not unity.

#### 1. Test and see if it will work before making changes to file.

Close up all firefox windows and open up the terminal. Type this command to launch firefox while preloading the libGL.so.1 library

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 firefox
```

Try viewing your flash videos full screen. If it works out, proceed to commit the command to file in the next step. If not, try the other instructions in the tutorial.

#### 2. Commit changes to file.

Open up the terminal and run the following command:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

This will open gedit in root mode and open up the firefox.desktop file.

Look for this line:

```
Exec=firefox %u
```

and change it to:

```
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 firefox %u
```

Log out and log in again.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a follower error: sudo: gksu: command not found
  
 when I input                           sudo gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

Comment: Ah. That should be either `sudo` or `gksu`, not both. Preferably `gksudo`. Do `sudo apt-get install gksu`. Then do `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.

Comment: @muru Corrected.